# Example of removing side borders on C64

Tags: assembly, c64, ca65

I know that it's possible to remove top and bottom borders in C64 using assembly, and I've found example codes for that. But I can't find any example code for removing the side borders (which was invented by 1001 Crew.)

Anybody know any examples of that?

Comment: Look for "soft scrolling". One link which looks good is this one: http://1amstudios.com/2014/12/07/c64-smooth-scrolling/ I know I did this kind of code, but it was twenty years ago so I forgot most of it already. ;) Have fun.

Comment: Thanks. It's a good link and I've found another very good link from the one you provided. But they both have nothing about side borders.

Comment: The register used for softscrolling is the one controlling the size of the border. That's how the softscrolling is implemented. By de-/increasing and shifting the border. AFAIK you can only use sprites in that open part anyway. No text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See my [answer to "How do I show sprites in the border on C64"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477444/how-do-i-show-sprites-in-the-border-on-c64/1477560#1477560) which contains the assembly code to remove the side and bottom/up border together with how it works.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get it to work on ca65, but this is my answer. I asked for an example code.

Answer (score 2):

Example code can be found on 'codebase'...

- http://codebase64.org/doku.php?id=base:removing_the_sideborders
- http://codebase64.org/doku.php?id=base:sprites_in_bottom_sideborder